# C# Comparing 2 data tables and changing font color to red for matching columns in data table 1

Tags: c#, visual-studio, compare

I have 2 datatables I am trying to compare. I would like on button press to compare the 2 data tables and if there is a matching record between both data tables to have datatable 1's associated column highlighted in red.

Example:
Before button click

**dt1**
john
sally
billy

**dt2**
billy

after button click

**dt1**
john
sally
**billy**  <-- This would be highlighted red

**dt2**
billy

I tried the following but was unable to get it to work correctly:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        var row1 = table.Rows[i].ItemArray;
        var row2 = csv_datatable.Rows[i].ItemArray;

        for (int j = 0; j < row1.Length; j++)
        {
            if (!row1[j].ToString().Equals(row2[j].ToString()))
            {
                csv_datagridview.Rows[i].Cells[j].Style.BackColor = Color.Red; 
            }
```

[image: data grid view compare]

I have also tried the following to see if I can get at least the correct amount of popups to display, but no bueno:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataRow rowSampleOne in csv_datatable.Rows)
    {
        string injuredplayers = rowSampleOne[0].ToString();

        foreach (DataRow rowSampleTwo in table.Rows)
        {
            if (rowSampleTwo[0].ToString().Equals(injuredplayers))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Something to see");
            }
            else
            {
                //do nothing
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm a little hesitant to ask, but have you checked that `rowSampleXYZ[0]` actually contains what you expect, i.e. the player name? Also, do the names in one of the tables probably contain padding spaces at the beginning or end (string.trim())?

Comment: Yes, I found matching records between both dt's and pasted both entries in notepad then highlighted each entry to ensure they are both identical matches with no trailing spaces. very good thought though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this sample:

```
if (!row1[j].ToString().Equals(row2[j].ToString()))
{
    csv_datagridview.Rows[i].Cells[j].Style.BackColor = Color.Red; 
}
```

You're turning the background red if the names are not equal.  Try something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    var row1 = table.Rows[i].Items[0]

    foreach (DataRow dr in csv_datatable.Rows)
    {
        if (row1.ToString().Equals(dr.Items[0].ToString()))
        {
            csv_datagridview.Rows[i].Cells[0].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
            break; 
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: @tintaafl
This is very close to what I am looking for. It is comparing the correct amount of matches between csv_datatable and table however the highlighting is not correct.  It will highlight the position of the match within table to csv_datatable but not the matching player.

Comment: Isn't the player name in column 0, as per your pic?

Comment: Yes, I will post a picture in a moment to the original post to demonstrate whats going on.